# Converting html string to html tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML string like this `test  <b contact-id=dd4a1dbf-66f2-4791-87ee-f01511df888d>@Sandeep Mohan</b>`. Now, I want to render that into `<b>` tag how I can do that? While rendering I'm getting this as a string and it is displaying in the web browser. I have an array and again I'm converting into a string. Again I want that string into HTML tag.

```
var fullName="<b contact-id="+index+">"+"@"+MentionsObj.fullName+"</b>";
         contacts[mentionIndex]=index.replace(index,fullName);
         }
      }
    }
contacts=contacts.toString();
contacts=contacts.replace(/,/g," ");
```

I'm converting the array into the string and then removing coma. Now, my return statement should return a html.

Comment: Share your code to understand this better.

Comment: Use `$(...).html("<b ... </b>")` instead of `$(...).text("<b ... </b>")`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "my return statement should return a[n] html" - an html what? some html? it's already some html, html *is* just a string.   If you mean DOM element, then `$(contacts)` or just append() or set (.html()) where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript function document.write(myHTMLString)

For example :

> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_write

Put everything you want in place of the "Hello World!", even html tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string into valid HTML element first. You can use [parseHTML](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) to change the string into HTML elements:

```
contacts[mentionIndex]=index.replace(index,$.parseHTML(fullName));
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a  element that you can append to your HTML element, you can use the following code.

```
var b = document.createElement('b');
b.setAttribute('contact-id', 'cake');
b.innerText = '@Sandeep';
document.body.appendChild(b);
```

Result:

```
<body>
  <b contact-id="cake">@Sandeep</b>
</body>
```